# Amazon API Marking orders as shipped

Tags: c#, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm currently using the amazon orders API to get order details. I then create orders on our system, which then get shipped from here.

I'd like to update the amazon orders once the goods have been shipped with our shipment number etc., but can't find any API to do this.

**Is there an API to update amazon's orders with shipment information, if so, where/what is it?**

I've searched all over the place, but haven't found anything so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no API to modify orders directly. However, you can use the feed submission API in MWS to submit a feed to confirm orders, mark them as shipped, and add shipment tracking information.

Here's where you'll get the detailed technical information:

MWS Feed API Reference is here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/189-7733093-6915107?ie=UTF8&section=feeds&group=bde&version=latest

You'll need to invoke SubmitFeed with a feed of type _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_

For the details of the feed itself, the info is : https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=au_200357600_cont_help?ie=UTF8&itemID=200357600&language=en_US

You're looking for an Order Fulfillment feed: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=ag_381_cont_341?ie=UTF8&itemID=381&language=en_US

There's a sample available on Seller Central.

Comment: Details would be great, thanks; I've not heard of the feed submission API before.

Comment: For anyone else reading, i could change the .com to .co.uk and the links still worked, so hopefully it'll work in other regions too.

Comment: When I try to access the seller central links I get this error message even the fact that I'm already logged in to the sandbox: Important Message You do not have permission to view this page.

Comment: Could be that the locations changed, or that you're not in the class of sellers that are allowed to submit feeds (e.g. individual sellers who do not pay the monthly fee, or you are subscribed to a different marketplace, UK vs. US).

Comment: Just wanted to add that a new PDF for order management seems to be available as of 2011: [Managing Orders With MWS API's](http://amazonpayments.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/Managing_Orders_with_MWS_APIs_en_US.pdf).  Seems to be considerably more coverage of the end-to-end process, with some pretty good examples in the appendicies.

Comment: Note: you can't update the tracking information for a package that has the same ASIN in it as another package. Known bug, Amazon just confirmed this to me.

Answer (score 4):

The ability to update shipping information (Ship Date, Carrier Code, Carrier Name, Tracking Number, Shipping Method) is available through the Feeds API.

After you've requested and stored Orders (and subsequently requested and stored Items for each order), you have the ability to update an order's (or an order's item's) shipping information in a similar fashion to adding or updating products you list on Amazon; that is, by uploading a delimited file to the Feeds API. To update an entire order's shipping information, simply provide the order-id. To update a specific item's shipping information, provide order-id and order-item-id.

A delimited file may include the fields: order-id, order-item-id, quantity, ship-date, carrier-code, carrier-name, tracking-number and ship-method. The order-id and ship-date fields are required. Fields must be defined on the first line of the delimited file. An example of this feed's file is available here: [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/ff/release_1_4/Flat.File.ShippingConfirm.*TTH*.xls](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/ff/release_1_4/Flat.File.ShippingConfirm._TTH_.xls)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a seller shipping items from their own warehouse (not a vendor, not Amazon fulfillment), orders can be marked as shipped using the [confirmShipment](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#confirmshipment) API call in the [SP-API Orders API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference).  See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630357/1003451) for more explanation.