# How do I update inventory and shipping tracking information through SP-API as a Seller?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I need to retrieve orders through Amazon's Seller SP-API, regularly update the inventory for all of our SKUs that are listed on Amazon as well as update Amazon with the shipment tracking number and status when the order is shipped out.

So far, I am using the orders-api to retrieve all the needed data on the order.

I have not found a straightforward way to update inventory for a SKU or update the shipment tracking number when the order is shipped out.

This is for a Seller, not a Vendor. The products are all stored in the seller's warehouse, not at Amazon.

What API endpoint should I be using that will allow the updating of inventory as well as updating of shipping information when the order is shipped out?

I've gone through every API endpoint listed [here](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/tree/main/references).

I have an ongoing Support Case with Amazon for the past 10 days and am currently on hold with Amazon Support for the past hour and the person on the other end of the line said they don't know either and have to find out.

Does anyone know what API endpoint / operation will do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the most reliable way currently to update listings and add shipping data is through the [Feeds API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-reference). There are many different types of feeds you can submit to Amazon, you can see them all [here](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feed-type-values).

- To update a listing's inventory, use the POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA feed.
- To add shipment and tracking information, use the POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA feed.

Feeds have been around for a while and are commonly used in the MWS API. So, you should be able to find plenty of resources online on how to submit a feed. Check out the [use case guide](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide) for a walkthrough on how it's done.

For some product types, you can use the [Listings Items API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-reference) to update product attributes, including (I believe) inventory. This would not apply to shipping however.

Comment: I have both the inventory and the fulfillment feeds built and generating a feed with the status "IN_QUEUE" but am having trouble getting the feed to actually process and update Amazon. Any pointers on this?

Comment: @jroyce During peak times, it can take some time for Amazon to start processing your feed. In my case, I continue to check the status every 30-60 seconds until it's `DONE`. At which time I request the feed processing report with the results.

Comment: I was able to successfully implement both of the above, thank you! But I am struggling with how to find the currently inventory for a specific SKU. I am a merchant seller, not FBA. Do you know what endpoint / feed I can use to get the listed available qty for a SKU?

Comment: @jroyce I'm glad you were able to get your feeds working. Getting the current inventory level is not something I've done. Try the [Listings Items API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-reference#getlistingsitem), be sure to pass `fulfillmentAvailability` on the `includedData` parameter.

Comment: @jroyce can you share the feed file for inventory update? I was able to successfully upload the feed file. I'm getting Done in status. But no changes in seller central.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon's SP-API actually **does** have an alternative to using a `POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA` feed, but it was surprisingly difficult to find this information.

- You **don't** want the [Merchant Fulfillment API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/merchant-fulfillment-api-v0-use-case-guide) — it's used to **purchase** shipping through Amazon using an API call... and to **automatically pay** for it with your Amazon seller account!
- You **don't** want the [Vendor Direct Fulfillment Shipping API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/vendor-direct-fulfillment-shipping-api-use-case-guide) — it has the [submitShipmentConfirmations](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/vendor-direct-fulfillment-shipping-api-v1-reference#post-vendordirectfulfillmentshippingv1shipmentconfirmations) API call, but this is a **vendor** API section, so it probably won't work for merchants.
- You **do** want the [Orders API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference) — specifically, the [confirmShipment](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#confirmshipment) API call does what you want.  There's even a [tutorial](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-use-case-guide#tutorial-4-confirm-a-shipment) in the [Orders API v0 Use Case Guide](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-use-case-guide).

Despite working with the Orders API before, I had never noticed the **confirmShipment** API call.  While searching for an alternative to `POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA` feeds, I found this Stack Overflow page that was asking the right question, but didn't have the right answer.

Eventually, I found this blog post: [How to confirm MFN Orders using SP-API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api-blog/docs/how-to-confirm-mfn-orders-using-selling-partner-api) — then I found the tutorial in the documentation: [Tutorial 4: Confirm a shipment](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-use-case-guide#tutorial-4-confirm-a-shipment)

Comment: This is great thank you. I just don't know why the sp-api has to be so confusing...

Comment: Yeah, no kidding!  I wish that the Amazon AWS side of the house implemented the API, they seem to be very good.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use ConfirmShipment method in Order API. It works well. But it only doesn't set "Delivery Service" field on the Amazon Interface. Any advice for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SubmitShipmetConfirmations SP-API to send multiple tracking numbers to amazon

Comment: This question has already an accepted response